# Elasticsearch Indexing by BulkRequestBuilder getting slow down

Tags: performance, indexing, elasticsearch

Hi all elasticsearch masters.

I have millions of data to be indexed by elasticsearch Java API.
The number of cluster nodes for elasticsearch are three (1 as master + 2 nodes).

My code snippet is below.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
     .put("cluster.name", "MyClusterName").build();

TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
String hostname = "myhost ip";
int port = 9300; 
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port));

BulkRequestBuilder bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("my_file_path"))));
long bulkBuilderLength = 0;
String readLine = "";
String index = "my_index_name";
String type = "my_type_name";
String id = "";

while((readLine = br.readLine()) != null){

    id = somefunction(readLine);
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(readLine);
    bulkBuilder.add(client.prepareIndex(index, type, id)
        .setSource(json));
    bulkBuilderLength++;
    if(bulkBuilderLength % 1000== 0){
        logger.info("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + " data indexed.");
        BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
        if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
            logger.error("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " + bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
        }
    }
}

br.close();

if(bulkBuilder.numberOfActions() > 0){
    logger.info("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + " data indexed.");
    BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
    if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
        logger.error("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " + bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
    }
    bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
}
```

It works fine but the performance getting **SLOW DOWN RAPIDLY** after thousands of document.

I've already tried to change settings value of "**refresh_interval**" as **-1** and "**number_of_replicas**" as **0**.
**However, the situation of performance decreasing is the same.**

If I monitor the status of my cluster using bigdesk, the **GC** value reaches 1 in every seconds like the screenshot below.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**=================== UPDATED ===========================**

Finally, I've solved this problem. (See the answer).

The cause of the problem is that I've missed recreate a new BulkRequestBuilder.
Performance degradation is never occurred after I've changed my code snippet like below.

Thank you very much.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
     .put("cluster.name", "MyClusterName").build();

TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
String hostname = "myhost ip";
int port = 9300; 
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port));

BulkRequestBuilder bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("my_file_path"))));
long bulkBuilderLength = 0;
String readLine = "";
String index = "my_index_name";
String type = "my_type_name";
String id = "";

while((readLine = br.readLine()) != null){

    id = somefunction(readLine);
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(readLine);
    bulkBuilder.add(client.prepareIndex(index, type, id)
        .setSource(json));
    bulkBuilderLength++;
    if(bulkBuilderLength % 1000== 0){
        logger.info("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + " data indexed.");
        BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
        if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
            logger.error("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " + bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
        }
        bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();  // This line is my mistake and the solution !!!
    }
}

br.close();

if(bulkBuilder.numberOfActions() > 0){
    logger.info("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + " data indexed.");
    BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
    if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
        logger.error("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " + bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
    }
    bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at using the [`BulkProcessor`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920902/elasticsearch-java-bulk-batch-size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't recreate again a new Bulk after Bulk execution.

It means that you are reindexing the same first data again and again.

BTW, look at BulkProcessor class. Definitely better to use.

Comment: Would you please add some words explaining why BulkProcessor is definitely better to use?

Comment: Basically because it automates everything for you. Less code to write as a developer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any clue if one performs faster than the other ?

Comment: BulkProcessor is a layer on top of Bulk API. So same throughput.