# ElasticSearch 1.7 (Spring Data ElasticSearch) update by query takes lot of time to update documents

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, nosql, spring-data-elasticsearch

My application allows updating multiple elasticsearch `documents` in single request.

I use ElasticSearch `BulkRequestBuilder` to update all such documents in Bulk.

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = elasticSearchClient.prepareBulk();

documents.forEach(id -> {
                UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequestBuilder(elasticSearchClient)
                        .setType("MyDocumentType")
                        .setIndex("MyDocumentIndex")
                        .setId(id)
                        .setDoc("fieldName", "valueToBeUpdated")
                        .request();

                bulkRequestBuilder.add(updateRequest);
            });

//update in bulk
bulkRequestBuilder.get();
```

All the documents are updated with `valueToBeUpdated` but ElasticSearch internally takes time to update all the documents but the call to `bulkRequestBuilder.get()` returns even before documents are updated. (Indicating `Async` nature of ElasticSearch engine).

Could anyone please suggest how to make it a `Sync` updates of all documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the core issue (may be default nature) with updates taking time by the `ElasticSearch` engine.

By default the ElasticSearch engines updates are `ASYNC` in nature (as I pointed in my question already). There are couple of links which are explaining this default behaviour.

e.g. ElasticSearch `GET` API [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) states that in order to get the document , elasticsearch engine does a `refresh` in order to visible all previous updates if any. This hints that `ASYNC` nature of elastic search is causing immediate search of my documents not providing me updated documents.

As of now to continue with existing behaviour, trigger bulk update in `SYNC` as follows.

```
bulkRequestBuilder.setReplicationType(ReplicationType.SYNC).setRefresh(true).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually problems indexing/updating a lot of data comes from [`segment merging`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html) from ES . 
One tip from ES people is to disable refresh before indexing/updating a lot of data.

You can achieve this updating index refresh_interval before indexing to `refresh_interval=-1`, and once all your data is indexed return it to your previous index configuration.

[Tune-indexing-speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_disable_refresh_and_replicas_for_initial_loads)

Comment: Disabling refresh will not be helpful as I mentioned the process is ASYNC and once the call returns back to caller, a new search document is triggered assuming that all the documents are updated in previous successful call. And this makes the search call getting old documents.

Comment: the .add doesnot call indexation. If you bulk you have to update/insert everny n (let s say 1000) documents. Here you build a hude request, and update in a one shot. loop on your documents, update every 1000 and reset your requestbuilfer, reiterate.

Comment: Seems that I'd misunderstood your question, in other hand as @LeBigCat says you need to recreate your bulkRequest once in a time.
Here another post related to `bulkRequestBuilder` that may help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950788/elasticsearch-indexing-by-bulkrequestbuilder-getting-slow-down