# How to give jest bulk insert batch size?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

```
bulkRequest.addAction(new Index.Builder(pubAdStatsGeoWiseModel)
.index(PublisherStatsConstants.geo_wise_ad_users_by_day_index)
.type(PublisherStatsConstants.geo_wise_ad_users_by_day_type).
.id(upsertUniqueId(res)).build());

jestClient.execute(bulkRequest.build());
```

Here is my query to insert document,but I want to insert 1000 at a time.Is it possible to give batch size using jest?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried jest, but usually you need to construct your `bulkRequest` calling  `addAction` as many items you want to insert/update/delete at once.

Comment: There is no API to mention batch size

Comment: There's no way to tell bulkRequest which size will have, you can sent up to 1000 items (configurable in ES).

Maybe is worth take look to this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920902/elasticsearch-java-bulk-batch-size